# how to check if a variable is defined in hive from within the view?

Tags: fat-free-framework

I'd like to setup a `<check if='...'>` where the if statement is defined on a param being defined. Is there a way to access this directly using the view?

Comment: What about `<check if="isset(@var)">`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the variable on the if condition, it works:

```
<check if="@doesnotexist">
  <true>The variable exists (?!)</true>
  <false>The variable does not exist</false>
</check>
```

This is possible because when you try to retrieve a value from the [F3 Hive](https://fatfreeframework.com/base#TheHive), it returns `NULL` when the key does not exist. Per documentation, [`NULL` is considered `false`](https://fatfreeframework.com/views-and-templates#ConditionalSegments) for this verification:

> An F3 expression inside an if attribute that equates to NULL, an empty string, a boolean FALSE, an empty array or zero, automatically invokes `<false>`